# How to compare the contents of $var to a known string in fish shell

Tags: string, if-statement, variables, fish

i am trying to get fish shell to figure out if a certain python virtual environment is loaded.
I figured out that, if it is loaded, its path is saved in $VIRTUAL_ENV
so i wrote the following.

```
 if  test [ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "home/user/Code/Python/Project/final project" ]
    source "/home/user/Code/Python/Final_Project/finalproject/bin/activate.fish"
else
    echo "Venv Running"
end
```

but it keeps spitting out that something is wrong without specifying what.
The documentation isnt a huge help either, as i tried the [[  ]] notation for the test as well and cant find any specifics on variables

Does anyone know and can explain what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is an alias for `test`, so don't use both: choose one of

```
if test "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "home/user/Code/Python/Project/final project"
```

or

```
if [ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "home/user/Code/Python/Project/final project" ]
```

Comment: and here i was thinking the brackets limmit the if statement. Thanks